# manage permission with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to manage permission in my discord server.

I alwready made that:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def give_perm(ctx, someone, permision):
    await ctx.send(f"permission gived to {someone}, permision : {permision}")
    --> give to someone the permission : permission
```

Thank you for your help

AP

Comment: You need to either edit the channel or edit a role since users don't have specific permissions yet

Comment: @FluxedScript I just need to edit a role, and give it to someone like :  ```client.give_role(name, role) ```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a role that you just want to give to someone you can just use `add_role(someone, *roles)`. If you don't have a role but you want to create one and give it to someone you can use `create_role(server, **fields)` and then use `add_role(someone, *roles)` to give it to "someone."

* = args
** = kwargs

discord.py `add_role()` reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles

discord.py `create_role()` reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/api.html#discord.Client.create_role